# QTextBrowser SetHtml gives blank screen randomly

Tags: html, qt

I have developed an application in which i need to generate a Slip containing all the information entered by the user. To show the slip, i created a new widget screen on which i used a QTextBrowser to display the information.

I have used **QTextBrowser->SetHtml** to display the information, format the information etc.The information includes **"the Hard Coded titles"** as well as **"information stored in the database sqlite"**.

Its running fine on my system (PC) but when i uploaded it on my friends system (PC), I got a blank slip. It happens for few slips then it starts displaying the slip.

Here's my function :-

```
void PrintRecieptInfo::createHtml()
{
    htmlString.clear();

    const QStringList childGroup = settings->childGroups();

    if (childGroup.length() < MAXGROUPINRECIEPTSETTINGS){
        return;
    }

    initRecieptInfo();

    htmlString = "<table align='center' border='yes' width='450'>";

    if (rItem[1].status){
        if ((rItem[0].status) && (rItem[0].text != "")){
            htmlString.append( "<tr><th colspan = '5'><font size='2'><img src='" +     rItem[0].text + "'>" + rItem[1].text + "</th></tr>");
        }
        else {
            htmlString.append( "<tr><th colspan = '5'><font size='1'>" + rItem[1].text + "</th></tr>");
        }
    }

    if (rItem[2].status){
        htmlString.append("<tr><th colspan = '5'><font size='1'>" + rItem[2].text + "</th></tr>");
    }

    if (rItem[3].status){
        htmlString.append("<tr><th colspan = '5'><font size='1'>" + rItem[3].text + "</th></tr>");
    }

    if (rItem[4].status){
       htmlString.append("<tr><th colspan = '5'><font size='1'>" + rItem[4].text + "</th></tr>");
    }

    htmlString.append("<tr><td colspan='5'><hr></td></tr>");

    for (int i = 5 ; i < MAXMEMBER; i++){

        if (rItem[i].status){
            htmlString.append("<tr><td width='80'>" + rItem[i].title + "</td><td width='80'>" + rItem[i].text + "</td><td width='50'></td>");

            int tempIndex = i+1;


            while(!rItem[tempIndex].status){
                tempIndex++;
                if (tempIndex > MAXMEMBER){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (tempIndex < MAXMEMBER){
                htmlString.append("<td width='80'>" + rItem[tempIndex].title + "</td><td width='80'>" + rItem[tempIndex].text + "</td>");
                htmlString.append("</tr>");
            }

            i = tempIndex;
        }
    }

    htmlString.append("<tr><th colspan='5'><hr></th></tr>");
    htmlString.append("<tr><th></th></tr>");
    htmlString.append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td align='right'>Operator Signature</td></tr>");

    htmlString.append("</table>");
    ui->printSlip_textBrowser->setHtml(htmlString);

}
```

Can anyone guide me some solution for this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? If yes, it sounds like you need to copy QTDIR/plugins/imageformats directory from your computer to computer of your friend.

Comment: @llya thanks for your response. I need to prepare a client based stand alone application. So, I cant copy this directory to the client PC. Can I add these Plugins in .pro file ?? can give me more info on this ?? thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, check that the problem is in these .dll files. If yes, just copy 'imageformats' directory near you .exe file (I am sure you already copy 'platforms/qwindows.dll' there). Or you allowed to copy only one .exe file?

Comment: @llya, thanks for your guidance. I tried with your solution. but the issue remains the same. Its showing blank QTextBrowser.